# Read a file for ten seconds

Tags: python, logging

I'm working with Logfiles right now. My need is I want to read a file line by line for a specified period of time, say 10s. Can anybody help me if there is a way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You want the program to spend ten seconds reading as much as possible from the file? Or just what?

Comment: Is it okay, if it spends more than 10 seconds?

Comment: or read what was logged within a 10s window? the possibilities are endless ;)

Comment: It can be more than 10s also.. I just want read the entire file in whatever time that is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `tail` or `tac` using `Popen` and iterate over output until you find a line you want to stop. Here is a example snippet.

```
filename = '/var/log/nginx/access.log'
# Command to read file from the end
cmd = sys.platform == 'darwin' and ['tail', '-r', filename] or ['tac', filename]
# But if you want read it from beginning, use the following
#cmd = ['cat', filename]

proc = Popen(cmd, close_fds=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output = proc.stdout

FORMAT = [
    # 'foo',
    # 'bar',
]
def extract_log_data(line):
    '''Extact data in you log format, normalize it.
    '''
    return dict(zip(FORMAT, line))

csv.register_dialect('nginx', delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
lines = csv.reader(output, dialect='nginx')
started_at = dt.datetime.utcnow()
for line in lines:
    data = extract_log_data(line)
    print data
    if (dt.datetime.utcnow() - started_at) >= dt.timedelta(seconds=10):
        break

output.close()
proc.terminate()
```

Comment: Ok, then you *stop condition* is to check how many seconds passed, I will fix the example...

Comment: Sorry, I've accidentally edit your comment instead of adding my own

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def read_file(path):
    try:
        # open file for writing
        f = open(path, "r")
        try:
            for line in f:
                # do something
                pass

        # always close the file when leaving the try block 
        finally:
            f.close()

    except IOError:
        print "Failed to open/read from file '%s'" % (path)

def read_file_limited_time(path, max_seconds):

    # init Process
    p = Process(target=read_file, args=(path,))

    # start process
    p.start()

    # for max seconds 
    for i in range(max_seconds):

        # sleep for 1 seconds (you may change the sleep time to suit your needs)
        time.sleep(1)

        # if process is not alive, we can break the loop
        if not p.is_alive():
            break

    # if process is still alive after max_seconds, kiil it!
    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()

def main():
    path = "f1.txt"
    read_file_limited_time(path,10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Notes

The reason why we "wake up" every 1 second and check whether the process we started is still alive is just to prevent us from keep sleeping when the process has finished. time wasting to sleep for 9 seconds if the process ended after 1 second.